# Baking artifact in Unity

Tags: unity, lightmap, global-illumination

I am using unity 2017.1.0 f3, Enlighten baking, with Generate lightmap UV ticked in import settings. Also the object has prioritized illumination and the light map resolution is high. An example of the artifact is shown.

[image]

The lightmapping settings is as follows.

[image]

The issue doesn't appear in Realtime illumination.[image]

The object is marked static. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

*Lightmap stitching*

Lightmap seam stitching makes it easy to get rid of those annoying edge seams in lightmaps.

Fixed in newer unity version: 2017.2

[What's new in Unity 2017.2](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/10/12/unity-2017-2-is-now-available/)

Comment: I have tried that. No use.